# MySQL WHERE IN SELECT to hibernate criteria query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, where-in

How to create hibernate CriteriaQuery from next SQL code?

```
SELECT ffr.request_sender FROM friend_relations ffr
WHERE ffr.request_receiver=9 AND ffr.request_sender IN
(SELECT fr.request_receiver FROM friend_relations fr
WHERE fr.request_sender=ffr.request_receiver)
```

I have "friend_relations" table and 2 records (like "1,2" and "2,1") mean that user 1 is a friend to user 2. But if I have only 1 record from 1 to 2, it is not a done friend relation.

Comment: First, I'd look into converting it to a join query... which is what I do pretty much any time I see a correlated subquery.

Comment: I know, but, unfortunately, I can't do it. I need query "select all distinct users, where we have friend relation between me and this user AND friend relation between this user and me"

Comment: So, i did it. 
SELECT ffr.request_receiver FROM friend_relations ffr
JOIN friend_relations sfr on sfr.request_receiver=4 and sfr.request_sender=ffr.request_receiver
WHERE ffr.request_sender=sfr.request_receiver AND ffr.request_receiver=sfr.request_sender
It works faster, without second select, but I still don't know how to create it with CriteriaQuery

Comment: Yeah, I can't help with that; not familiar with hibernate; was just guessing a  join query might be easier to convert (and in my experience correlated subqueries are almost always slower than the equivalent join when one is possible).